# grep regex of 0 or many spaces

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I want to make a grep on a file based on a regex.

In the regex, I want to make comparison on a spcace or none space so I tried the following expression:    `/ {0,}/` but it does not work.

Here after my whole regexp

```
cat test.txt  | grep "\"cache_changes\":/ {0,}/\"xax.yby.zcz[ \"]"
```

How I can do it?

here after my file test.txt:

```
{ "nbr": "01", "parameter": "toto.aaa.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes":"xax.yby.zcz" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
{ "nbr": "02", "parameter": "toto.eeee.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xax.yby.zcz xa2x.yb2y.zc2z" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
{ "nbr": "03", "parameter": "toto.aaa.2.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xa2x.yb2y.zc2z xax.yby.zcz" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
{ "nbr": "04", "parameter": "toto.ffff.3.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xa2x.yb2y.zc2z xax.yby.zcz xa3x.yb3y.zc3z" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
{ "nbr": "05", "parameter": "titi.aaa.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xdx.yey.zfz" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
{ "nbr": "06", "parameter": "titi.eeee.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xdx.yey.zfz xd2x.ye2y.zf2z" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
{ "nbr": "07", "parameter": "titi.aaa.2.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xd2x.ye2y.zf2z xdx.yey.zfz" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
{ "nbr": "08", "parameter": "titi.ffff.3.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xd2x.ye2y.zf2z xdx.yey.zfz xd3x.ye3y.zf3z" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
```

The desired output is:

```
{ "nbr": "01", "parameter": "toto.aaa.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes":"xax.yby.zcz" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
{ "nbr": "02", "parameter": "toto.eeee.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xax.yby.zcz xa2x.yb2y.zc2z" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
```

Comment: Please include your desired output in the question. For parsing JSON, don't use `grep`, use [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command instead:

```
grep "\"cache_changes\": *\"xax.yby.zcz[ \"]" test.txt
```

With the test file provided in the question, here is what I get:

```
{ "nbr": "01", "parameter": "toto.aaa.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xax.yby.zcz" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
{ "nbr": "02", "parameter": "toto.eeee.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xax.yby.zcz xa2x.yb2y.zc2z" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
```

Comment: You should not use `cat` with program that can read data itself, like grep.

Answer (score 1):

Use `*` (*which repeats the previous token zero or more times*) instead of the repeatation quantifier `{}`

```
$ grep "\"cache_changes\": *\"xax.yby.zcz[ \"]" file
{ "nbr": "01", "parameter": "toto.aaa.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xax.yby.zcz" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
{ "nbr": "02", "parameter": "toto.eeee.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xax.yby.zcz xa2x.yb2y.zc2z" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
```

If you really want to use that quantifier, you need to escape the braces, like

```
$ grep '"cache_changes": \{0,\}"xax.yby.zcz[ "]' file
{ "nbr": "01", "parameter": "toto.aaa.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xax.yby.zcz" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
{ "nbr": "02", "parameter": "toto.eeee.1.bbb", "value": "45", "notification": "0", "cache_changes": "xax.yby.zcz xa2x.yb2y.zc2z" "set_cmd": "any_f xax.yby.zcz $val" }
```

Comment: What do you mean? I think the problem is mainly with your command itself. I just replace this `{0,}` in your input with `*`

Comment: `grep '"cache_changes":/ \{0,\}/"xax.yby.zcz[ "]' file`

Comment: I will put my file content  in the question and you can try your commands and you will see that nothing will be displayed

Comment: @MOHAMED there isn't a forward slash before `"xax`